# The difference between IntelliJ IDEA add library and maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, build

What is the difference between **IntelliJ IDEA  add library** and **maven dependency**? I try to migrate my application from java **8** to java **11**. I have an issue with one of the dependency. When I add it as a library in Idea, everything works fine. But if I add it as a maven dependency I got a runtime error
like a:

```
 [java] java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
 [java]   Bytecode:
 [java]     0000000: b800 2599 0007 b800 27b0 b800 2699 0007
 [java]     0000010: b800 27b0 bb00 1a59 b700 2ab8 0028 57b8
 [java]     0000020: 0027 b0                                
 [java]   Stackmap Table:
 [java]     same_frame(@10)
```

I've tried to import the dependency on different scopes, but it didn't work.

Comment: Which dependency are we talking about?

Comment: It's my internal module which contains java fx 13 modules inside and a lot of others. They were repacked with maven-dependency-plugin.

Comment: Could it be because of dependencies inside my module conflict with others?

Comment: Verify error is a JVM problem that shouldn’t happen. Consider filing a bug report if you are certain your artifact is generated correctly.

Comment: Do I got it right? Your code runs fine inside IntelliJ IDEA, but when you built it with Maven, it causes the error from your question? And you are using JavaFX? When you start the Maven-built code, did you start that on the same machine as your IDE runs on? Or did you move that Maven-built stuff onto another machine and started it there?

Comment: Yes, got it right, the project works fine inside IDE, but doesn't work via maven. I've built the dependency on the same machine where I used it.

Comment: I'm still investigating it. As I understood the issue connected with classpath and the difference in the building process between idea and maven